# What was wrong with this edit that changed code to be more efficient?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer, specific-edit

This question is based on [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/3939277) - from what I can tell, this situation isn't covered by it.

---

**What did I do wrong here?** I thought I was operating under SO best-practices, but there was clear and swift pushback on my actions.

More importantly for future readers: **Is it discouraged to edit an answer's code to make it more performant, if those edits don't change the result nor formatting of the code?**

---

When trying to find a solution to a warning in Xcode, I found this question: [How to resolve: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57134259/3939277)

In reading through the answers, I saw that some were very inefficient, and some were somewhat inefficient, iterating through collections multiple times when one iteration would suffice. Remembering [guidelines for when to edit code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/3939277), I edited [two](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57899013/5) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57169802/2) to improve their performance, making sure to maintain the original author's intent and the code's behavior. Here's the paragraph I had in mind when doing this:

> If changing the syntax errors or typos would result in the code doing something other than what the answer says it will, consider creating a comment or a separate answer explaining your change. If posting another answer with only that change seems like it won't provide added value to future visitors, it probably doesn't change logic or functionality and should be an edit instead.

After doing this, I found another answer to the same question whose code was identical to the edit I made to one of these. Since [the general advice is to "try to avoid providing 'answers' that are [...] duplicates of existing answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts), and since the *Not an answer* flag's description reads "[...] It should possibly be an edit, a comment, [...], or deleted altogether.", and keeping in mind the above paragraph, I flagged this (and a couple others) as "Not an answer", since I believe they would be better-suited as edits. I made sure to leave comments on these answers explaining my reasoning, some of which have since been deleted.

Through these edits and flags, I kept in mind this advice from [those guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/3939277):

> Answers are intended to be resources for future visitors

Knowing my experience trying to solve an issue, I would really rather see one working answer using a given approach, knowing it's been edited to be the best it can be, and I would rather not see two or more conflicting answers, then try to figure out which contains the best code and why. I know that, because so few would be willing to weigh the pros and cons of each individual answer, and would be much more likely to just take the accepted or most-voted answer's code and move on, I didn't want such inefficient code to be copy-pasted into an untold number of codebases. Hence why I felt inclined to edit those accepted/upvoted/oldest answers, and flag those which I saw as the same answer with some basic edits applied.

I was then told, very definitively, that my comments, my flags, and one of my edits were not welcome:

> [image: A screenshot of two comments telling me why I shouldn't've done this, and my responses]

> [image: Three declined "Not an answer" flags]

Comment: Why not just write your own answer?

Comment: If you see non-performant code, please write your own answer that is performant. Edits are supposed to preserve the author's intent, cleaning up formatting and making minor corrections, not improving the approach. _I found another answer to the same question whose code was identical to the edit I made to one of these_ -- upvote that post and downvote the ones you edited, optionally leaving a comment explaining that they're non-performant.

Comment: Also, please move away from the idea that you know what's best and should apply it unilaterally to the top post in a thread. Even if you "know" you're right and have something that _seems to you_ to be objectively better, imagine what the Q&A would look like if everyone did this. It'd be a nightmare. Even if these assumptions were accurate (which is extremely dubious--it stands to reason that people are wrong in edits about as often as they are in posts), it's much better to see all given solutions to the problem and let better answers rise to the top by voting, not by force.

Comment: The "downside" is that unscrupulous programmers might blindly copy and paste from the top answer and wind up with worse code than if they'd scrolled down, so your suggestion is to try to hide access to information and rewrite history in order to protect these people. It's not our job to ensure that they understand how to research, think critically for their use case, research all options, etc.

Comment: @RobertLongson as I explained in this question, I believe that would decrease the quality of the page by adding more confusion to those looking for an answer. "[...] I would rather not see two or more conflicting answers, then try to figure out which contains the best code and why. I know that, because so few would be willing to weigh the pros and cons of each individual answer, and would be much more likely to just take the accepted or most-voted answer's code and move on [...]"

Comment: @ggorlen I never intended to present myself as "knowing what's best". All I'm trying to do is what I thought I was told. I wasn't trying to "unilaterally" apply anything. If I imagine what SO would look like if everyone did this. I imagine we'd have one question, whose answers are all separate, valid, correct approaches, without duplicates nor slight variants, and all edit histories preserved for those interested.

Comment: @ggorlen I see a problem with the approach of letting better answers rise to the top by voting: when one answer has 100 votes, and then a better alternative arrives as a separate answer, the better alternative starts at 0, and as the webpage itself decreases in interest/SEO/whatever, the votes flow in slower, and the better one might never get more votes. Viewers who don't vote will just come, see the accepted or highest-voted answer, take it, and move on. I don't want to rewrite history - that's preserved in the edit history

Comment: I use StackOverflow because it's best at helping others come, find what they need, and leave. Forums like XDA, social sites like Reddit, other Q&A sites like Quora, they all have massive flaws that SO overcame with decisions like being able to edit answers, closing duplicates, separating comments and answers, etc. In that way, it is our duty to maintain that goal of aiding research and providing an easy way to get answers fast.

Comment: What you're proposing removes information about competing approaches from the explicit answer thread and buries it in the edit history, which sidesteps the designated stream of discourse that's used to determine quality (votes and comments). Yes, change is slow. If something accrues hundreds of upvotes, it takes time to unset that. Doing an edit that changes intent does rewrite history--to a visitor, the votes correspond not to the historical state of the post in some edit but to its current state. Edits are simply not the designated mechanism for proposing or imposing alternative solutions.

Comment: _In that way, it is our duty to maintain that goal of aiding research and providing an easy way to get answers fast_ -- I'd rather not further debate the philosophical goals or duties of SO here. Quite simply, the rule is that edits [must not "change the code logic or functionality"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). Incidentally, for the reasons I state above, I believe this is for the best but it's also beside the point of asking whether the edits are valid under the current guidelines.

Comment: @BenLeggiero From my point of view, the most useful interaction would be to upvote the "better" solution, downvote the other one and add a comment explaining problems with the code. Why? Because it is useful for learning what one _shouldn't_ do and how code looks that does the job, but isn't as performant as it could be. In the past, I learned from bad answers as well.

Answer (score 26):

As the person who got edited here, I would like to inject my own perspective.

At first, I didn't object to what the OP ("Ben") was doing in editing my answer's code; it seemed a modernizing improvement in the language.

Then, however, another answerer ("pommy") piped up, and I scrolled the page further down, and realized two things:

**(1)** Ben had changed my answer to look like pommy's answer - in fact, to *be* pommy's answer. But pommy's answer postdated mine. *It* is the improvement on my original answer. I have upvoted pommy's answer; I like it better than mine.

So to turn my answer into pommy's answer (a) lies about the way the history went, and (b) makes me appear to *steal* pommy's answer, which is just what I don't want do to.

**(2)** This has all happened before, as you can see if you look at the earlier comments on my question. I'd forgotten all about that! I maintained then that changing my answer to look like pommy's would be wrong, and I am merely being consistent in maintaining it now. If Ben had looked carefully, he would have *seen* that I have already objected to exactly this kind of change.

In short, without regard to what SO's "best practices" are, *my* best practice on this particular question needs to be that I maintain the history fairly and give credit where credit is due, i.e. to pommy. To put words in my mouth that makes it look as if I am doing otherwise is a misrepresentation of *me*, and I object to it.

On the whole, I find Ben's comments (and, as I now learn, flags) on other answers throughout that same page to be officious and unnecessary. It looks like he is trying to change the *whole* history of answering here. That, I would maintain, is none of his business. It is not his job to "groom" the answers on this or any other question. That is *our* job, meaning we, *the voting public*. That is what Stack Overflow is: crowdsourced grooming that causes the cream to rise. The correct approach, it seems to me, is to *answer or vote* (or both, though that is discouraged). If he wants to downvote my answer and upvote pommy's, that's fine with me. If he wants to downvote other answers, that's fine. If he wants to give his own answer, that's fine. But making me say what I did not say is not fine.

Comment: I think you are ascribing intent to me where there is none. As I described, I'd edited yours before I knew pommy's existed. I also did not touch the non-code parts of your answer, so I didn't "change [your] answer [...] to _be_ pommy's answer". I was not lying about history; I was updating your answer, as you said, to modernize and improve it. If one were to think you stole pommy's answer, they need look no further than the dates and edit attributions. You attest to this by saying you looked back on the edits and saw it happen before. I'm sorry I didn't do that first.

Comment: I didn't ever mean to put words in your mouth. Could you let me know when that happened?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was referring to the editing of the code in my answer. As the answer appears to come from me - it has my gravatar at the bottom, along with my name, which is a link to my SO profile - it consists of what I am calling "my words". If someone else writes those words, that "puts words in my mouth", much as if one were to change a legal document after I've signed it. No analogy is perfect (each thing is just the thing it is, and not some other thing), but that's how I was envisioning it.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see now! Is this why Community Wiki answers exist? So there's less social stigma to editing them?

Comment: @matt I agree 100% with your position. I acknowledged your answer as a great improvement on the accepted answer, but saw that its performance and conciseness could be improved on. I decided for a separate answer instead of a comment to provide more visibility for unexperienced coders. I never considered editing your answer, and would not have if had the privilege for it. Later comments to both our answers provided other relevant discussion points, which looked odd after Ben changed both two top-rated answers a year later.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question "**Is it discouraged to edit an answer's code to make it more performant, if those edits don't change the result nor formatting of the code?**"

It is discouraged when that might be seen as one of these:

1. **Rewriting history**

   In a vacuum, modernizing an answer's code to use current best-practices, or to be more performant, is okay, so long as the result of the code is the same. However, when someone has already done this in a separate answer, then your edit might be seen as rewriting history, insofar as it appears, on the surface, that one of the two answers simply copied the other, whereas that's not the truth.

   In these cases, it's best to upvote the better answer and downvote the worse.
2. **Putting words in the answerer's mouth**

   If your code edit gives the answerer a voice or opinion that doesn't match their own, that can be seen as an insult to the answerer. Make sure that your edit preserves their opinions.
3. **Unilateral application of your viewpoint**

   If your code edit makes it appear that you are applying a subjective viewpoint without any external consensus, that can be seen as suppressing others' viewpoints in favor of your own. To avoid this, first think about your code edit, and if there is a chance that this perception might occur, first create a Meta post asking if that edit is appropriate.