# What can I do to ask better questions on Meta?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta

It seems that recently when I come to Meta trying to better understand SO, my questions are downvoted as "does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful."

I post these questions in earnest, trying to be a better SO citizen. I try to show my research effort in the questions, and be as clear and open as possible in them so that I can be useful if others have similar questions. **What am I doing poorly and how can I improve?**

---

Here are the specific questions which got me thinking about this:

- [Why was this answer-should-be-an-edit-or-comment flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403355/453435)
- [What was wrong with this edit that changed code to be more efficient?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401472/453435)

Comment: @Ben: Downvotes mean something different on meta, by convention.  They can signal disagreement with the question's premise, for example.  Votes carry no rep penalty here, and it's much more difficult to get banned here, so I'm not sure it really matters.

Comment: You have a good number of upvoted questions. 3 or 4 downvoted questions is just a part of participating here. I have, maybe, 10 deleted answers that got downvoted heavily. It just means people disagree with you.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta don't mean that people actually think it's not useful, it's more "I don't agree with this post".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for the explanation. I'm not worried about bans or rep loss, just want to be a better citizen and asker 

Comment: @BenLeggiero Even Moderators get downvoted, CM's get downvoted, everyone gets downvoted. There will be times when people disagree with you.

Comment: @BenLeggiero If it's an consolation, my questions on meta range from a score of 182 to -22. The mob is fickle :-)

Comment: Perhaps related on MSE: [Common reasons why your meta post may be negatively received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333476/241919)

Comment: Helpful reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta

Comment: On your first bullet point, don't use the "Not an Answer" flag unless you see something like "I have the same problem, any update" or ["I like turtles"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y).  "Not an answer" literally means it's something other than an answer, not "this didn't answer the question that was asked."

Comment: On your second bullet point, the general rule of thumb is "don't change code, except for minor formatting issues."  Stack Overflow isn't a Git repository; edits to improve code are generally not welcome.

Comment: But neither of my comments changes the fact that people can still downvote based on the question's premise.  That's just the way meta works.

Comment: I think that before posting your Question, you need to read [all the posts in the FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow). Downvotes also means: I've seen this before. I'm not implying I agree with the reception of your posts.

Comment: Thanks, @Scratte! That came around a few years after I joined so I didn't know about it. I'll bookmark it! 

Comment: :) It's quite easy to find though once you *know* where it is. [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png) -⮞ [FAQ Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgK4k.png) :)

Comment: Yeah the tooltip is a cake. I mean the cake is a tooltip. Darnit! I mean the tooltip is a lie.

Comment: lol thank you again, @Scratte. I did go through the help center early on, but figured I had a hang of it after a few years. I'll set a reminder to read through it every couple years now 

Comment: I think the answer and comments here are right to say that up/downvotes are treated different on meta, but I'm also struggling with people downvoting a question like "Why X?". I feel that this is rude and does not encourage users to ask a question. Also very uncommon for a support forum for a product, which meta at least partially is. I think mixing pure support questions with proposoals, rfc's etc is a bit problematic and leads to the disappointing situation for users which are looking for pure support

Comment: It's one of these meta rules. If you ask "What is wrong with X?" people kind of assume that you think that nothing is wrong really and if they think that something is wrong they downvote the question. A slight change in question title "What are all the things that are wrong with ...X?" might be change the voting behavior. People try to read your intent here. So basically try to stay as neutral as possible in questions. Questions containing "or" or "how to handle..." are typically good choices.

Comment: @hek2mgl "..people downvoting a question like "Why X?".." Not all "Why X?" questions are useful. What shall I do if I think it's not a useful question to ask?

Comment: While I don't experience the toxicity that SO is infamous for, Meta is in another league. Darn you'll have to tread softly if you don't want to trigger the meta crew the wrong way...

Comment: Check out the top 10 highest upvoted and top 10 most downvoted questions. It will give you a good sense of the community and values. Votes on meta are driven by opinion so if your goal is upvotes then post stuff that people find favorable but votes are not related to rep so just try to search for your question before posting if you don't want to feel like you "asked a wrong question"

Comment: @Trilarion What is useful or not, in a support forum, depends on the opener. For them it's useful, obviously. My suggestion is: if you are not planing to answer support questions, just don't do anything.

Comment: @hek2mgl Voting isn't just for the opener though, it's also for anyone who may view it subsequently. Enough downvotes gets it off the front page so that stuff that may actually be useful to people viewing it can be there, and a flurry of upvotes for things that are useful for a large audience might even get it onto Hot Meta Posts. Limiting our voting to "Is this useful to the person who opened it" is short sighted.

Comment: @DavyM Then I would say that meta is not the right format for pure support questions. I'm thinking this since meta exists actually. Support is something like: Hey, how can I help you? Don't get me wrong, I think it's clear that "personal support" for everyone who asks wouldn't work. But still other formats than meta could be thought of for pure support questions. Like no votes at all, separate area, etc ... for example.

Comment: @hek2mgl It's definitely not only support. Meta is also the place for discussing policies or feature requests or in general terms self-government. But I would totally support going back to the old way of voting on questions purely in terms of clarity and research-fullness and maybe a bit of usefulness. Questions should be as neutral as possible and opinions as well as agreement should be reserved for answers. That would also require that askers formulate their questions differently sometimes.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, meta has mixed goals: be a support forum and be a "rfc forum" at the same time, with same rules. I think that is not optimal. I agree with all the other points you say, I just don't think that meta, incl voting is the only or best way to get there

Answer (score 15):

Downvotes may mean disagreement like some commenters stated, but they can also mean the things in the tooltip. Particularly with your first question, I'm astounded that people would state that downvotes mean "I don't agree with this post" when confronted with the downvotes on the first of those two. I mean, how do you disagree with a question that is literally asking "Why X?". Do they mean "You're wrong to ask *why*?" Yeah, no, that's not a helpful way to explain away the downvotes.

That [first question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403355/7795130) is a question we see on Meta a lot. I mean **a lot**. Like daily a lot. Nobody seems to get along with the "Not an answer" flag on the first try. Some people (and most of the moderators, who are the ones who decline or accept those flags) are of the belief that the Not An Answer flag should be used for things that are [objectively not answers at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/7795130), such as "Thanks" answers, answers that just ask a new question, answers that ask for clarification, or attempts to bump the question. The main reason that they don't handle off-topic or wrong answers is because the moderators aren't expected to have any domain knowledge when they look at it, they can know it's not an answer regardless. For that question, a moderator viewing your flag sees a code block and easily assumes it's a valid answer, declining the flag.

For that first question, you got an answer, which was good because it solved your issue, which is what you came here to find. But it (1) shows a lack of research effort (The Meta FAQs include "When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?" which explains those 4 reasons to flag that I just mentioned), and (2) Is not useful for future readers, because there are so many questions just like it already. Remember, votes are mostly for future readers looking for an answer to know how worthwhile that question is.

Maybe the downvotes were a "Oh no, not this again" kind of gut reaction or any other number of reasons, but you don't need to go further than the tooltip on that one to find valid reasons for it to be downvoted.

So in that case, what you can do to improve is research the question more, and if you choose to ask a new question, make sure it's different enough from existing questions to be useful.

For your second question, that one might fall more into the "disagreement" category, as each answer is basically "This is why that was wrong." I can imagine people making a case for the question not being useful because it's based on a faulty assumption, but I'm not convinced by that. It seems to be well researched and clear, and it's useful to anyone else confused by that same issue, so I would probably be willing to call those disagreement votes. However if anyone would like to make a suggestion as to how that second question could be improved, please do.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why we need to disagree with a question by downvoting it. Answering it and upvoting the answer seems like a clearer approach, and the decision back then to basically shortcut the process seems like it has resulted in quite a bit of confusion over the years. It's probably the useful part of the tooltip.

Comment: Over time, I realise how much of a pain it is to search for existing questions or subjects on any Stack Exchange website. Maybe I don't know how to search for very specific keywords.

Comment: @Clockwork No, search on SE is abominable and useless. Use Google with the site: prefix for a much less painful time. Why SE Inc. doesn't just use Google's own search and stick a pretty frontend on top of it, instead of forcing us to use their own internal implementation that *literally doesn't work*, is beyond me (but then, many of SE Inc.'s decisions are beyond me).

Comment: @Trilarion There's absolutely no need for us to downvote based on disagreement at all. The Help Center only mentions "Disagreement" in the [context of feature requests](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), where disagreeing that it's useful is the same as saying it's not useful.

Comment: The whole idea of disagreeing being a reason to downvote things in a way that's different from saying it's not useful is a completely cultural thing that I don't like, and I especially don't like people commenting saying "The downvotes are just disagreement" on posts that have obvious problems. (But I don't see such problems on question #2, so my only guess as to why it's being downvoted is some sort of "You shouldn't do it that way" disagreement with the premise. I don't get it, but I know it occurs.)

Comment: @DavyM People forgot that agreement voting is only on feature requests and it saves the time to write an answer before dismissing the question. However, it mixes judgement of quality with opinion losing information. By now it seems to be ingrained. People sometimes even use close votes as surrogates for downvotes, kind of saying I disagree and I don't want to answer it and I don't want anyone else to answer it. Doesn't happen all the time but maybe on every tenth question or so.